# Assets field within Grid field does not display

Tags: assets, grid

I have an issue using an Assets field (2.2.2) within a Grid field (EE 2.7.2). Here is my code:

```
{home_slideshow}

<img src="{exp:img_resize src="{home_slideshow:slide_image}" width="745" height="558"}" alt="Front Show Image" class="hero-image">

{/home_slideshow}
```

When I use Assets, the image displays fine but other Assets fields on the same page display nothing. When I swap out Assets and use a basic File field the above image does not display (and returns an empty img tag) but the other Assets fields on the page work fine!

I have already eliminated img_resize as the problem by removing any references to it - the issue remains the same.

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: Just ran into this bug as well. I hope it's fixed soon.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue as well, and Pixel and Tonic confirmed it to me as a known bug in Assets 2.2.2. Email them for a fix: support@pixelandtonic.com

Comment: Pixel and Tonic is working on a fix for this. They told me the fix would be in the next release which should be out next week (around 17th of Januari).